# Meaning of 資料共 in the context of web conferencing

Tags: translation

The literal translation for "資料共" seems to be "total" (Google Translate) or "Documents" (Rikaichan).

How would you parse it and interpret it in the context of web conferencing? It's supposed to be the equivalent of "web conference".

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you've got the word correct and that there are no mistakes?

Comment: Yes, it's a copy paste from the specification. As Gary said, usually we would use「ネット会議」.

Comment: Sorry if it's not concrete enough. I, myself, don't have much more information. The answer I got was enough, I just needed to be sure.

Comment: Thing is, [Rikaichan doesn't recognize 資料共; rather it parses 資料 only as "documents"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Lah6E.png)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Ok, after a while I improved a little and could understand how to translate it.

It means "Document sharing".

Comment: Perhaps they meant to type `資料共有`?

Comment: @snailboat: I would agree but this went through reviewing and constant usage from Japanese partners who validated the translation. I think it is meant to be a shortened version of what you suggest (there are many others options for sharing and for the sake of avoiding extra repetition and visual noise they might have removed it)

Answer (score 3):

Would be helpful to see further context, but in this case I would interpret it as "Documentation". I would use the word 「ネット会議」to describe a web conference.

Comment: This is exactly what was formerly on the button. This button opens a browser and lets you connect to a web conference. The Japanese contractor asked to change this to 資料共. The purpose didn't change though. Is this weird?

Comment: Maybe your contractor is mixing up the words 'conference' and 'reference'? It's the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think 資料共有 can be shortened into 資料共. In any occasion.

Actually I first read it as しりょうども; 資料 + 共 (ども: somewhat derrogative plural suffix usually used only for people) which didn't make sense. I never thought of the word 共有 (きょうゆう) until you mentioned it, and I don't think anyone of Japanese native speakers would.

Then what is this? Sorry I don't have an answer...

Comment: Why answer then? Also I say it again, the meaning is as explained in my answer. Now whether this is correct to use it I think everyone made it clear that it is not. Nevertheless, my question is already answered.